# I try to implement like and unlike functionnality in the frontend with react js and redux with Nodejs and Sequelize MySQL DB

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting with react and redux and I have a problem with the like/unlike functionality
I try to implement like and unlike  functionnality in the frontend with react js and redux

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { likePost } from '../../actions/post.actions';
import { UidContext } from '../AppContext';



const LikeButton = ({ post }) => {
    const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
    const uid = useContext(UidContext);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleLike = () => {
        dispatch(likePost(post.id));
        setIsLiked(true);
    }

    const handleUnLike = () => {

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const like = post.likers.map((like) => like.id)
        if (like.includes(uid)) {
            setIsLiked(true);
        } else setIsLiked(false);

        //console.log(like.includes(uid))

    }, [uid, post.likers, isLiked])

    console.log(isLiked)

    return (
        <>
            {isLiked === false && (
                <>
                    <span onClick={handleLike} className="card__like__heart__light">

                    </span>
                    <span className="card__like__length">
                        {post.likers ? post.likers.length + " " + "Like" : 0 + " " + "Like"}
                    </span>
                </>
            )}
            {isLiked && (
                <>
                    <span
                        onClick={handleUnLike}
                        className="card__like__heart__full"
                    >
                    </span>
                    <span className="card__like__length liked">
                        {post.likers ? post.likers.length + " " + "Like" : 0 + " " + "Like"} </span>
                </>
            )}


        </>
    );
};

export default LikeButton;
```

my LikeUpdate Action

```
export const likePost = (postId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios({
            method: 'patch',
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/post/${postId}/like-post`,

        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                dispatch({ type: LIKE_POST, payload: { postId, likers: res } })
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

My Like Reducer

```
    export default function postReducers(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case GET_POSTS:
                return action.payload;
            case LIKE_POST:
                return state.map((post) => post.id === action.payload.postId ?
                    { ...post, likers: action.payload } : post)
    
            default:
                return state
        }

}
```

My backend and likeController

```
const models = require('../models');

const { User, Post, Like } = models;
const jwtAuth = require('jsonwebtoken');



module.exports.likePost = async (req, res, next) => {

    //Getting user Id 
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    const decoded = jwtAuth.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    const userId = decoded.id;

    //Params 
    const postId = req.params.postId;

    try {

        const post = await Post.findByPk(postId)
        if (!post) return res.status(404).json('Post not found.')

        const user = User.findByPk(userId);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json('User not found');

        //Verify if the user already like this post
        const postLiked = await Like.findOne({
            where: { userId, postId }
        })
        if (postLiked) {
            return res.status(409).json("Post already liked!");
        }


        await Like.findOrCreate({
            where: { userId, postId }
        }).then((createLike) => {

            if (createLike) {
                //Create Like if no Like table is no found
                post.update({
                    likes: post.likes + 1
                })
                return res.status(201).json('Vous avez aimé cette publication.')
            }
        }).catch((err) => res.status(500).json("Cannot update like in the post." + err))


    }
    catch (err) {
        return next(res.status(500).json('Like Error.' + err))
    }

}


module.exports.disLikePost = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    const decoded = jwtAuth.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    const userId = decoded.id;


    const postId = req.params.postId;

    try {

        const post = await Post.findByPk(postId)
        if (!post) return res.status(404).json('Post not found.')

        const user = await User.findByPk(userId);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json('User not found');


        await Like.destroy({ where: { userId, postId } })
            .then((dislike) => {
                //Check if post is already dislike and update default values to 0
                if (dislike <= 0) {
                    post.update({
                        likes: post.likes,
                    })
                    res.status(409).json("Vous avez déjà disliker ce post.")
                } else {
                    //Delete  Like table and decrement values - 1
                    post.update({
                        likes: post.likes - 1
                    })
                    return res.status(200).json("Vous n'aimez plus ce post.")
                }
            })
    }
    catch (err) {
        return next(res.status(500).json('Like Error.'))
    }
}
```

The backend works very well and adds the likes in the Like table and adds the number of likes on the post The problem is at the frontend level with React and Redux because when I click on the like button the store does not add the value of the like and the backend returns an error
[image]

Comment: So... what is the error?

Comment: BTW, your `//Verify if the user already like this post` step can be eliminated entirely if you redesign your table to use a composite primary-key, e.g. `CONSTRAINT PK_Likes PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, PostId )`

Comment: The error is that when I click on the like button to add a like to the post the like is not added and the store crashes and the backend does not respond, while on the backend it is added and works correctly

Comment: Also, doing the `likes: post.likes + 1` increment in application-code instead of directly in a single transaction will result in race-conditions, e.g. imagine two concurrent Like requests for the same post.

Comment: I tried this approach works well on the backend but I have the same problem with react and redux when I click on the like button the store does not increment the data and the server crashes